# oracle add column with value based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to add a column "tag" based on value of "LEASE_ID_count" with ORACLE.

But i get this error :

> value too large for column "CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_TAG"."tag" (actual:
> 7, maximum: 3) , caused by: OracleDatabaseException: ORA-12899: value
> too large for column "CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_TAG"."tag" (actual: 7,
> maximum: 3

```
select "COMPANY_CODE", "LEASE_ID_count",
(CASE WHEN "LEASE_ID_count" IN ('3','4', '5') THEN '3 à 5vh' WHEN "LEASE_ID_count" ='1' THEN '1vh' WHEN "LEASE_ID_count" ='2' THEN '2vh' END) "tag"
from "CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_TESR"
```

Any idea please to help me ? thanks

Comment: This `SELECT` is not causing that error.  It would seem that the `SELECT` is part of an `INSERT` and the error seems quite clear in that context.

Comment: I realise a fresh set of eyes can sometimes see something obvious you can't, but the message is pretty clear here. How is the `tag` column defined? The error suggests `varchar2(3)`. And how many characters are in `'3 à 5vh'`? (Incidentally, colleagues are unlikely to thank you for using quoted identifiers; and this seems like something you should do in a view or as a virtual column in your existing table, not as a new table you'll have to maintain?)

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, you mean that i have to replce select by insert? not clear for me

Comment: varchar2?? i dont see this in the error message :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  The error message is referring to `"CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_TAG"."tag"`.  This is from a table that has no obvious reference in the query.  Okay, perhaps `CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_TESR` is a view that references that table.  That is possible.

However, the error message is about *storing* data into that column, not referencing it.  So, my best guess is that you have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_TAG (COMPANY_CODE, LEASE_ID_count, tag)
    <your select here>;
```

And the column `tag` in this table is defined as 3 characters.  Clearly, `'3 à 5vh'` has 7 characters which is more than 3 which causes an error.  Hence the error.

Oracle does have a lot of functionality lurking around.  Even so, it is hard for me to think of how a `SELECT` could cause this error with no DML involved.

As Alex Poole very correctly notes:  write the queries without double quotes.  Quoted identifiers just make queries harder to write and read.